End of 80's/Begin of 90's movie - Man trapped in a castle or mansion
I watched this movie at the end of 80'/begin 90' (I was a little child). I think it was a drama movie and a love story was involved.
This movie may be Italian, Spanish or Argentinian (maybe), but I'm just guessing.
I remember only the final scene of the movie: for some reason, a man goes into a castle (or just and old mansion maybe) and remains trapped inside it.
The movie fade out with the man screaming on one of the window, which has cell bars. The point of view of the camera is in the outside of the building, looking at the man, slowly moving far from him.
So, the man must be trapped in the first floor, or in the second floor maybe (not in the basement).
